# How to override a yum module state for multiple packages using environment variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yum, ansible-2.x

This is my code currently -

```yaml
- name: software
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: install packages
      yum: 
        name: 
          - ansible
          - docker
        state: latest
      become: yes
```

So when I run this I get the latest ansible and docker installed.

What I want is for the default value of state to remain latest, so if I just run the playbook the latest versions are downloaded, as it is now. However I want a way for me to override the state for one or both using environment variables(extra vars) when running my playbook from the command line.

So I can choose what version of ansible or docker to install.

Is there a way?

Comment: Since you mention your playbook is working as expected, I took for granted the problem was a copy paste error and hence corrected your example so it is valid. Please make sure your examples are correct when pasting them.

Comment: @Zeitounator sorry about that and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not think this is the best way to manage software version and that the I consider the following a bit ugly, here is a in-a-nutshell example to get you on track for your experimentation (untested, you may have to adapt a bit):

```yaml
---
- name: software
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    ansible_raw_suffix: "-{{ ansible_yum_version | default('') }}"
    ansible_suffix: "{{ ansible_yum_version is defined | ternary(ansible_raw_suffix, '') }}"
    docker_raw_suffix: "-{{ docker_yum_version | default('') }}"
    docker_suffix: "{{ docker_yum_version is defined | ternary(docker_raw_suffix, '') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: install packages
      yum: 
        name: 
          - "ansible{{ ansible_suffix }}"
          - "docker{{ docker_suffix }}"
        state: "{{ yum_state | default('present') }}"
      become: yes
```

With the above, you can:

- install to the latest version if first time install

```
ansible-playbook software.yml
```

- install a specific version of one or both softwares:

```
ansible-playbook software.yml -e ansible_yum_version=2.9.2 -e docker_yum_version=20.10.6
```

- upgrade to the lastest version

```
ansible-playbook software.yml -e yum_state=latest
```

I will let you go on with this to add more features (e.g. allow downgrades) if you feel you still want to walk that path.

Comment: If I was to separate ansible and docker in 2 yum modules , would it be easier to do something like this on the state - "{{ <have a variable that I can set from extra vars) | default('latest') }}" .... currently I don't know where that yum_state is coming from ?

Comment: [state does not take a version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameter-state)